# How to resolve SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen inside a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I have changed the permissions of the certificate in the host machine [mounted to docker container] to -r-xr-xrwx 1 But still when i run nginx in docker container i am getting error. **SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen**